# "Bloody" vs "bloodied" (when referring to human blood)

Tags: word-choice

Someone from the UK suggested I use *bloodied* instead of *bloody* do describe objects/people that are covered with blood. (Because *bloody* could be mistaken by the curse.)

Is this a good suggestion? Example sentence:

> I pull out the meat from the fridge and carry it to the bloody kitchen
>   table.

Comment: I'd have chosen a less strange example, but I wouldn't be so precious as to avoid using 'bloody' where appropriate.

Comment: I think it would depend on the context as to whether I would read that as a swear word or not. Out of context my default reading of it is the swear word.

Comment: Even though I'm American and I don't even use "bloody" as a curse, the word "bloody" in your example sentence is confusing because I wouldn't expect a table to be bloody before having meat put on it. (Maybe *after.*) But I would expect UK as well as American speakers to speak of e.g. "bloody knives", and I see no reason to replace that phrase with "bloodied knives". If you must avoid "bloody" I think "blood-covered" might sound better than "bloodied" as a substitute in some cases.

Comment: There's a possibility of I interpreting it along the lines of "that bloody kitchen table that always wobbles when I chop meat". But it's unlikely. If you described it as "*already* bloody" you would deal with the surprise @sumelic referred to. Also unless followed by "late", "annoyed" etc., "already bloody" weakens the hint of the (very mild) curse.  Calling it a butchers' block instead would have a similar effect.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, or *bloodstained* if the blood has dried. *Blood-covered*, to me implies it's still wet. *Bloodied* seems most often to be used to describe a person or animal covered in blood as a result of injury or combat, but not an inanimate object. *Bloody* may be a mild curse-word but it's hard to avoid the connotation - a bit like trying to use *damned* in its literal sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bloody" is more common as an adjective (in both UK and U.S.), while "bloodied" often takes the verb form...in this case past perfect continuous tense, as in a kitchen table that *had been bloodied*. Based on your example sentence and stated interest in description, my vote is for "bloody." Even if your audience is culturally habituated to the British colloquialism (which is technically not a curse word but an adverb/intensifier), I doubt there would be much confusion when reading the term in context. Bloody up that text then! Once it's been bloodied there's not much you can do anyway.